# What is the file name + extension for a file with a period as the first character (example: .txt)?

Tags: filenames, file-extension

I'm trying to find an authoritative answer on this matter, but it's difficult. Wikipedia kind of dances around the issue but isn't explicit enough.

For `.txt` (to use an example), is the base name null/empty and the extension `txt`? Or is the base name `.txt` (including the period) and the extension null/empty?

And what about something weird like `.a.b`?

I realize there might be some operating system differences, so I am interested in what they are + what the recommended OS-agnostic "rule of thumb" to use is. I plan to program the parsing logic in the server for a web app, so it needs to analyse filename strings sent from many different operating systems.

Answer (score 3):

If you want OS-agnostic, there is no such thing as a "file name extension". Certain operating systems may in fact use these to determine the program to open a file with, or even go as far as explicitly restricting them (think FAT with 3 characters maximum).

But the information could also be gathered from [magic numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29) or other heuristics. Filename extensions are just metadata—where that data is stored doesn't matter from an OS point of view. For example, in *nix, a script file includes a [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) at the top of the file. The shebang tells you which interpreter the file should be run with, e.g. `/bin/bash` or `/usr/bin/env ruby`, etc.

In the *nix world, a "basename" is just the file name with any leading components (i.e., paths including the last `/`) stripped. So, the basename of `.txt` would be `.txt`. And the basename of `/usr/bin/foo` would be `foo`.

Files starting with dots are called [dotfiles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot-file). They are in no way special other than that in Unix-like operating systems they're supposed to be hidden from directory listings by default. Their basename is their full name, so `.bashrc` is actually called `.bashrc`. A dotfile does not have an extension, per se.

Therefore, if you want to stay OS-agnostic, try to take the basename (in the *nix sense of the the word) and store that. Anything else will *always* be ambiguously defined.

You can additionally try to extract an extension, which would be the entire basename components starting from the last dot found, e.g. `foo.tar.gz` would obviously be a `.gz` file and not a `.tar.gz`. Only when unzipped with gzip, it then becomes a `foo.tar`, which would be untarred by tar. And so on.

Comment: I have always thought of extensions as an organizational tool. For the purposes of the question, it seems that if the `.` is index 0 then it is {part of name} otherwise if last occurrence then {extension}